# Place an Edit Button on the view node page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I don't use the Drupal Tabs because they interfere with my CSS but I need the functionality of the Edit tab to be on that screen so that a user can edit the node after reviewing it. 

Any ideas on how to do this? Functions? tpl placement? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a custom module as follows.

In yourcustommodule.module you implement hook_preprocess_node(). In there you check if the user has permissions to edit the node and you set the edit link.

```
function yourcustommodule_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (node_access("update", $vars['node']) === TRUE) {
    $vars['edit_link']['#markup'] = l(t('Edit'), 'node/' . $vars['nid'] . '/edit');
  }
}
```

In the node.tpl.php template in the theme you print the edit link if it is available.

```
<?php if (isset($edit_link)) : ?>
  <p><?php print render($edit_link); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you do not have a node.tpl.php template in your theme folder than copy the one from modules/node.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Views Format "Fields", one of the fields that you can add is "Edit Link."  It's pretty flexible; it will tell you what text to display in the link.  That's probably the preferred option.

If you're not using the "Fields" format, it gets trickier, especially since you're already interfering with some basic drupal styling. I'd need more information about your View and your skill set to recommend a method that doesn't cause more problems.

As a sidenote: I learned Drupal theming from the outside in, and used to use CSS that would interfere with the underlying drupal mechanics like tabs and contextual links.  I've moved away from that; I find very few cases where I need to interfere with native styling-- and for those I can use custom .tpl's to get around.

EDIT: Ah.  If you're not using views, a custom page .tpl is probably the best way to go.  If you're not familiar, the structure for any node edit link is `'/node/<NID>/edit'` (for clean URL's) or `'/?q=node/<NID>/edit'` for old-style URL's.  Depending on how your path aliases are set up, `'/<url-alias>/edit'` may work as well but the previous ones are more reliable.

[This link on drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1785758)  gives a few options.

Comment: Hey Dagger,thanks for the reply. i hear you on moving away from using a lot of css to make these types of changes. I'm not using Views for this. I use Views a lot (Views is awesome) but here I am using a Page Variant on the node/view native page. so the path is... docresource.org/content/title-of-the-node

Comment: Hey Dagger,thanks for the reply. i hear you on moving away from using a lot of css to make these types of changes. I'm not using Views for this. I use Views a lot (Views is awesome) but here I am using a Page Variant on the node/view native page. so the path is... docresource.org/content/title-of-the-node.   a few months ago, i might have used CSS to move and restyle the edit tab at the top left but I know this is a cludgy way to do this. I'm OK at PHP (fine with HTML, CSS) and am comfortable with subtheming and using my own tpl files in order to do overrides.

Comment: i have never done anything quite like this but I feel like adding the edit function in a button via PHP is the "right " way to do this. if I am wrong or there is a better way, please let me know. but I don't plan on using Views for this. I'm going to stick with the page variants. thanks again for the info! check out my drupal blog if you're bored. startlearningdrupal.wordpress.com thanks, pj

Comment: Edited the original with my recommendations.

Comment: i found a really good way to make this work. i know about tokens and have tried before to use the NID to reference this within context, but couldn't make it work correctly. but I found a great module called https://drupal.org/project/menu_token   that will allow me to use the token [node:nid] in the url for a normal menu item. so the url is /node/[node:nid]/edit. there is an additional setting that allows for context. i place that menu item on the panel page variant  and i am good to go! thanks for your help! your post helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can write a theme file(.tpl) for u specific case and theme page in whichever way u want